# Python Kademlia DHT

Tags: python, csv, pycharm, dht, kademlia

I am very lost on this assignment.  We are supposed to use kademlia to create 3 python files.  The 2 files are nodes and then the third are a set a query the DHT application.  We are also given a CSV file that we must import and and send the data to the DHT network.  **Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!**  Here is the assignment:

You will first need to create an initial starting node (see code below). This will start on your local system on port 8468.

---

```
# Modified from: https://kademlia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html

import logging
import asyncio

from kademlia.network import Server

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
log = logging.getLogger('kademlia')
log.addHandler(handler)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.set_debug(True)

server = Server()
loop.run_until_complete(server.listen(8468))


try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    server.stop()
    loop.close()
```

---

Next, you will need to start another local node of the DHT application on port 8469 (see code below).

---

```
# Modified from: https://kademlia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html

import logging
import asyncio

from kademlia.network import Server

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
log = logging.getLogger('kademlia')
log.addHandler(handler)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

bootstrap_node = ("localhost", int("8468"))
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.set_debug(True)

server = Server()
loop.run_until_complete(server.listen(8469))
loop.run_until_complete(server.bootstrap([bootstrap_node]))

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    server.stop()
    loop.close()
```

---

Finally, the follow code will allow you to query the DHT application and add key/value pairs (see below).

---

```
# Modified from: https://kademlia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying.html

import logging
import asyncio

from kademlia.network import Server

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
log = logging.getLogger('kademlia')
log.addHandler(handler)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

async def run():
    server = Server()
    await server.listen(8470)
    bootstrap_node = ("localhost", int("8469"))
    await server.bootstrap([bootstrap_node])

    await server.set("myKey2", "myValue2")

    result = await server.get("myKey2")
    print("Get result:", result)
    server.stop()

asyncio.run(run())
```

---

Now that you have the code for two nodes and the code to set and query the DHT application, using the DHT_Data.csv file, write a Python program that imports the CSV file and sends that data to the DHT network. Additionally, write some code that will take a list of the keys in the DHT_Data.csv file and query the DHT application to show that you can query and return the values.

Here is a screenshot of the CSV file:
[DHT_Data.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2188E.jpg)

Here are Screenshots of my code:

[KademlaiDHTServer.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqLaC.jpg)

[kademliaDHTAdditionalNode.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3GrC.jpg)

[kademliaDHTSetandQuery.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGyDu.jpg)

Comment: What is the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How do I pass the CSV file through the three python files?